# How to pass parameters for Debian installer (.deb)

Tags: software-installation, debian-installer

I am developing a specialized Unix application that has the Debian installer (.deb). It needs to get few simple string values during installation. These values must be picked by the post-install bash script.

What would be most reasonable, approved way top pass these values to the post install script?

Answer (score 5):

The [“approved”](https://www.debian.org/doc/debian-policy/ch-binary.html#prompting-in-maintainer-scripts) way to do this is to use [`debconf`](https://www.debian.org/doc/packaging-manuals/debconf_specification.html). This might seem surprising if you’re not interested in actually prompting the user for the information; but beyond prompting, `debconf` is based on the notion of package configuration variables, and prompting is only one of the ways that can be used to provide the values for those variables. [The `debconf-devel` manpage](https://manpages.debian.org/debconf-devel.7) describes how to use this.

In your case, you’d declare the variables in your package’s templates and `config` script, and then use them in your `postinst`. To feed the values in without prompting, you’d then use pre-seeding:

- write a file containing the keys and values:

  ```
  <package> <config key> <config type> <value>
  ...
  ```
- before installing the package, store its configuration:

  ```
  debconf-set-selections < preseed-file
  ```

See [Automating the installation of individual debian 8 packages with interactive prompts](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/449885/86440) for an example.

Comment: debconf documentation sucks. Are there alternative solutions for this?

Comment: @JesseBarnum that depends on exactly what you’re trying to do. Feel free to [ask a question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) with details of your specific scenario.