# How do I ask for user input and pass into a file while debian package installation?

Tags: dpkg, arguments, debian-installer

I would like add some parameters into my `.service` file such hostname, IP, username, password, during debian package installation.

I created a debian package installion for my python script but I do not know how to get parameters from user and pass the arguments into the `.service` file or create a `.service` with arguments.

Answer (score 1):

See [How to pass parameters for Debian installer (.deb)](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/482092/86440) for information on how to ask questions during package installation.

Once you have the values you want, passing them into the `.service` file can be done in a variety of ways. One of these is to write the values to a drop-in file, typically in `/etc/systemd/system/yourservice.d/parameters.conf` (`yourservice` must match your service; `parameters` can be anything, the significant part is the `.conf` extension). Such drop-in files are read after the unit file and their contents are added to it; see [`systemd.unit`](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.unit.html) for details (or `man systemd.unit` on your system).

Comment: Would you consider the question a duplicate of the one you linked?

Comment: Not quite, because there seem to be two questions: one about asking questions during package installation (which is a dupe), and one about passing the information to the service. Thanks for asking!

Comment: Yeah, the second point was what made me hesitant to flag it as duplicate. So I guess while technically "it lacks focus", we can leave it as it is ...

Comment: Sorry for my late answer and thanks for the reply. I used `preinst` which is automatically executed before installation starts. You can check the [link](https://github.com/eminaktas/get-of-metrics/blob/v1/get-of-metrics/DEBIAN/preinst) to see my solution.

Comment: That’s a shame, but it’s your package ;-). Your approach works but you’ll have trouble dealing with upgrades.