# Common practice for config files

Tags: debian, configuration, packaging, deb

I'm making a file manager system for managing my projects. My package is named `filesystem`. I need a config file that stores the path to the root of my file system.

I think I need to create a file `/etc/filesystem/root.conf` and add it to `DEBIAN/conffiles`. If the file doesn't exist I want to prompt the installer for a root directory. Else I want to keep the root directory the same (for example when upgrading).
I think the prompt should be in `postinst`.

Should I add the file to `conffiles`?

Should I add the prompt in `postinst`?

How do I add an option to `apt install` that forces a prompt? (I have read about `--force-confnew`)

I need the file to be deleted in `apt purge`.

Comment: Aside from your question, I deeply urge you to name your software something, *anything* else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To prompt the user for a root directory, you should [use `debconf`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/482093/86440). This will allow you to prompt the user, while still allowing pre-configuration, and explicit re-configuration using `dpkg-reconfigure`. See [Configuration management with `debconf`](https://www.debian.org/doc/manuals/developers-reference/best-pkging-practices.en.html#configuration-management-with-debconf) and [`man debconf-devel`](https://manpages.debian.org/debconf-devel.7) for details, in particular [Config file handling](https://manpages.debian.org/debconf-devel.7#Config_file_handling) in the latter.

Purging a configuration file handled using `debconf` should be done in `postrm`; see [the relevant chapter in Debian Policy](https://www.debian.org/doc/debian-policy/ch-maintainerscripts.html#details-of-removal-and-or-configuration-purging). Files which are manipulated in maintainer scripts as a result of `debconf` prompts or stored values shouldn’t be listed in `conffiles`, otherwise your users will end up with confusing questions during upgrades.