# Why is it necessary to run 'dpkg-reconfigure' on bodged installs?

Tags: debian, software-installation, dpkg

I recently became acquainted with the restorative power of `dpkg-reconfigure` following a bodged installation of the GNU `mailutils` package. At the end of the installation process a dialog (ncurses?) appears prompting the user to make choices and fill in some blanks. That's all well and good, and I suppose if you're proficient enough, you simply avoid making any mistakes in the "post-install configuration dialog", or `PICD` as I'll call it in the sequel.

I'm not proficient, and needed to re-run the 'PICD'. Not yet being acquainted with `dpkg-reconfigure`, I assumed that it was necessary to un-install, then re-install. But when I did that, the installation completed - but the 'PICD' did not re-appear. I tried a `reboot`, but still no 'PICD'!?!

Eventually, someone clued me about `dpkg-reconfigure`, but `dpkg-reconfigure mailutils` also failed to restore the 'PICD'. It turned out that it was ***not*** `mailutils` that needed to be reconfigured - it was `postfix` - the MTA. This took a while to sort out because the Debian packager for `mailutils` cleverly hid `postfix` under an innocuous *"virtual package"* called `default-mta`. And so the *magic* required to get a second chance for *re-configuration* was: `dpkg-reconfigure postfix`. This discovery enabled my *trial-and-error* approach to configuration, and I finally completed it.

But this has raised a question or two for me:

1. What is it that disables presentation of the 'PICD' on subsequent installations? I mean, how does the install script know that the user has already seen the 'PICD'? Is there some value recorded & saved by the installer to prevent the 'PICD' *replay*?
2. *Why* does the installer disable subsequent presentations of the 'PICD' (without the `dpkg-reconfigure` incantation)? What is the point of that actually?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. The `postfix` package uses `debconf` for its configuration. You can think of this as a kind of registry in Debian; it’s used by most packages which need configuration during installation. You can see the values it currently stores by running `debconf-get-selections`. A package can determine during installation whether a value it expects has already been stored in the `debconf` database.
2. Once a value is set in `debconf`, general practice is to *not* show the corresponding dialog during package installation. This avoids asking the user the same question multiple times, in particular every time a package is upgraded (this is [strongly recommended by Debian Policy](https://www.debian.org/doc/debian-policy/ch-binary.html#s-maintscriptprompt)). It also allows packages to be pre-configured, so they can be installed with custom settings without user interaction; this is common practice for automated installations where many systems need to be configured in the same way.

As you determined, if a configuration setting needs to be amended, the best way to proceed is to run `dpkg-reconfigure`. Another possibility is to *purge* the affected package, and re-install it: if nothing else depended (even weakly) on `default-mta` or `postfix`, `sudo apt purge --autoremove mailutils` would have cleared everything without your having to determine that `postfix` was the package actually at fault. (In practice, you’d have to purge `postfix` itself since many packages will prevent `default-mta` from being an auto-removal candidate, including `unattended-upgrades` or `cron`.)

Comment: OK... thanks for the edit, and I can see some logic in your answer; it's not perfect (-the logic I mean, not your answer - IMO), but what is? WRT `debconf-get-selections`, I see numerous entries in my `debconf` re `postfix`.  Just out of curiosity, does *any* entry block a PICD replay - or is it a specific one? And finally, is there any way to edit the `debconf` registry? (a quick search didn't reveal anything).

Comment: Which entries prevent “replay” depends on each package’s logic. In most cases removing an entry would cause at least the screen for that entry to be shown again. `debconf-set-selections` can be used to modify settings (see [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/449888/86440)). `man 7 debconf` is in the `debconf-doc` package.